# Java Http Proxy

Tags: java, http, proxy, deflate

I'm writing a small proxy in Java that basically picks out 2 specific files and does some extra processing on them. One URL it just grabs some info out of the content before passing it along. The other file I want to filter the response content, which is just xml deflate encoded (I want to remove some child elements).

Now, the proxy works fine when I just pass though all content. However, when I try to filter the xml file it doesn't actually send the content to the client ???

Here is some code:

Within the Thread run() method that is spawned when accepting a Socket connection, once I determine the request is for the file I want to filter, I call:

```
filterRaceFile(serverIn, clientOut);     // This won't send content     
//streamHTTPData(serverIn, clientOut, true); // This passes through fine (but all content of course).
```

and here is the filtering method itself:

```
private void filterRaceFile(InputStream is, OutputStream os) {
    // Pass through headers before using deflate and filtering xml
    processHeader(is, os, new StringBuilder(), new StringBuilder());        

    // Seems to be 1 line left, inflater doesn't like it if we don't do this anyway...?
    try {
        os.write(readLine(is, false).getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       

    InflaterInputStream inflate = new InflaterInputStream(is);
    DeflaterOutputStream deflate = new DeflaterOutputStream(os);
    int c = 0;
    try {
        DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xdoc = db.parse(inflate);
        Node id = xdoc.getElementsByTagName("id").item(0);
        Node msg = xdoc.getElementsByTagName("message").item(0);
        StringBuilder xml_buf = new StringBuilder("<race>\n");

        xml_buf.append("<id>").append(id.getTextContent()).append("</id>\n");
        xml_buf.append("<message>").append(msg.getTextContent()).append("</message>\n");
        xml_buf.append("<boats>\n");

        NodeList allBoats = xdoc.getElementsByTagName("boat");
        int N = allBoats.getLength();

        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            Node boat = allBoats.item(i);
            Element boat_el = (Element)boat;                
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(boat_el.getElementsByTagName("lat").item(0).getTextContent());
            double lon = Double.parseDouble(boat_el.getElementsByTagName("lon").item(0).getTextContent());
            double dist = Geodesic.vincenty_earth_dist(proxy.userLat, proxy.userLon, lat, lon)[0];
            if (dist <= LOS_DIST)
            {
                String boatXML = xmlToString(boat);
                //<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> is prepended to the xml
                int pos = boatXML.indexOf("?>")+2;
                boatXML = boatXML.substring(pos);
                xml_buf.append(boatXML);
                ++c;
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("%d boats within LOS distance\n", c);

        xml_buf.append("</boats>\n");
        xml_buf.append("</race>");

        byte[] xml_bytes = xml_buf.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
        deflate.write(xml_bytes);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // flush the OutputStream and return
    try {
        os.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

I also have a simple pass through method that simply writes the server's InputStream to the client's OutputStream, uses readLine also and works fine - ie any other url shows up in the browser no problems, so readLine is ok. The boolean parameter is to let it know it is reading from a deflate stream, as it uses mark and read internally, which isn't supported on deflate streams.

XML is very simple:

```
<race> 
  {some data to always pass thru}
    <boats>
       <boat>
          <id>1234</id>
          ....
          <lat>-23.3456</lat>
          <lon>17.2345</lon>
       </boat>
       {more boat elements}
     </boats>
   </race>
```

And it produces the xml I want it to send to the client fine, but the client just doesn't receive it (shows content-length of 0 in a web-debugger, although there is no Content-Length header in the original response either)

Any ideas as to what is going on, or what I should be doing that I am not ??

Comment: NOTE: I have also tried completely rebuilding the response, same result no content in the client...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any error, but if you are already using a `Document`, can't you just modify the document and then use your XML library to write the whole Document out? This seems more robust than manual XML formatting.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a call to deflate.close() after deflate.write() in order to flush the output and correctly close the stream.

Comment: I don't understand how the previous answer which doesn't actually answer the question is valid, but my answer is not. The original post asked "Any ideas as to what is going on, or what I should be doing that I am not ?" and the answer is he didn't call .close() on deflate.