# Using a proxy to replace/modify http response data

Tags: java, proxy, response, deflate

I have wriite a small proxy (in Java), with the intention of modifying specific data from a web server response. The data is a deflate compressed XML file: only some of the elements do I want to actually be received by the client.

I have no problems with the proxy functionality, but when I try to send my modified xml in place of the server's response, the client receives nothing (web-debugger shows content length 0) - I *am* sending data though, atleast there IS data in my app being written to the Socket's output stream.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939091/java-http-proxy) for more details and some Code. I won't post it twice.

Comment: why did you post the same question twice?

Comment: I thought title of 1st Q was not specific enough.